# SQL Server casting a varchar to int

Tags: sql-server, casting, varchar

I have the following scenario:

```
DECLARE @m VARCHAR(50) = '000000001'

WHILE (@m <= 10)
BEGIN
        PRINT @m
        -- Increment the iterator
        SET @m = @m  + 1
END
```

When I run the above code I get:

```
000000001
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The problem is, I need the result to be as following:

```
000000001
000000002
000000003
000000004
000000005
000000006
000000007
000000008
000000009
000000010
```

I want the eight 0's to show up before the number when it is increasing, and it will be seven 0's when the number reaches 10. I tried the following but it didn't work, there will be as you guessed eight 0's before the 10.

```
DECLARE @m VARCHAR(50) = '1'

WHILE (@m <= 10)
BEGIN
        PRINT '00000000' +@m
        -- Increment the iterator
        SET @m = @m  + 1
END
```

Basically I want to keep only 9 digits, this might sound stupid but what can I say (My boss wants it like that).

Comment: You should tell your boss that your RDBMS is for storing and retrieving data efficiently. Formatting should be left for the client application.

Comment: Telling that to your boss may be a bit career limiting...

Comment: @Szymon if telling your boss **what he's hiring you for in the first place** is limiting your career options then you should get the hell out of there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really must:

```
DECLARE @i int; Set @i = 1;
WHILE @i <= 10
BEGIN
    PRINT RIGHT('00000000' + cast(@m as char(9)), 9);
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```

But please don't. Data should be stored **raw**, and only formatted at display time, preferably by the client application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that code:

```
DECLARE @m VARCHAR(50) = '000000001'

WHILE (@m <= 10)
BEGIN
        PRINT SUBSTRING('00000000' + @m, LEN('000000000' + @m) - 9, 9)
        -- Increment the iterator
        SET @m = @m  + 1
END
```